# how to call renderpartial from spark

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using both spark and .aspx view engines. My partial is in aspx so i'm tring to call from my spark engine.

I've seen something like the following

${Html.RenderPartial("HeaderControl")}

Seems like i'm missing a reference, can't really see what.

> Dynamic view compilation failed.
>   d:\Website\Views\Retailer\Index.spark(11,23):
>   error CS1061:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'RenderPartial' and no extension
>   method 'RenderPartial' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

spark

```
<use namespace="MvcContrib.UI"/>
<use namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Grid"/>
<use namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Pager"/>
<use namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Grid.ActionSyntax"/>
<viewdata model="EStore.Domain.ViewModel.RetailerViewModel"/>


<content name="MainContent">
  ${Html.RenderPartial("HeaderControl")}
</content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess, sorry, because I don't use spark:

```
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
```

`RenderPartial` is defined in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions`. However I don't generally need to import anything to use it for regular MVC 2.